# Owl Carousal Hides The Divs after some Interval but data appear

Tags: jquery, owl-carousel

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Lyjw.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVjn1.jpg)

I Have added Owl Carsoul Every thing Works Fine but the owl Carousel fadeout effect hides the slider for some time interval then it make it appear again

i think the clown class is getting active at late intervals , please suggest
what should i do ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check how to create How to [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example so that you can get a much better response to your question.

Comment: Please improve formatting and spelling! If you look at your own question here, It should be quite obvious that its quality is quite poor!

Comment: Great, I will join your English class , but if you understand my questions mean please give me some decent solution . I will sent my shashi tharoor to you soon..